# How do I set Ethernet speed for Ubuntu 20.04 permanently?

Tags: networking, suspend, ethernet, 20.04, disconnect

Ubuntu will automatically try to connect my Ethernet connection at a speed of 1000 Mbps. I need the network to connect at 100 Mbps since my cable is unable to support any higher. As it stands now, I have to wait around 5 minutes until Ubuntu finally selects 100 Mbps as an option, or I have to use ethtool to manually set it.

How can I change the network settings so that Ubuntu 20.04 always connects at 100Mbps, even on reboot or suspend?

Edit: I have tried using 'nm-connection-editor' to change the duplex and speed, as offered as a solution below. Unfortunately, picking any option other than 'ignore' (under 'link negotiation') will prevent Ubuntu from connecting to a network.

Comment: You can use `ethtool` https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/download-install-ethtool-under-debian-ubuntu-linux/, and [more options](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/ethtool.8.html).

Comment: Why not fix the problem? Assure that you're using cat 5e or cat 6 cables.

Answer (score 6):

With Ubuntu Desktop, you can set it up with the grafical interface applet `nm-connection-editor`

Run it via gnome start menu <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or from a terminal window
`nm-connection-editor`

Then, on the first window, select your network interface and hit the cog
on the second window, setup the interface Speed & Duplex

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm on my way finding a working method but on the latest updated 20 if I follow this instruction, the cog is grayed out and says "No polkit authorization to perform the action"

running "nm-connection-editor" from terminal with sudo ends with "cannot open display"

Comment: @kuz8 : for elevation, use pkexec nm-conn... but

Comment: thank you, with Alt+F2 and entering "pkexec nm-connection-editor" it asks my password (which has wheel) and then nothing pops up. 

In latest 20.04 standard network edit dialog in settings doesn't provide option to edit negotiation and speed. 

I remember on CentOS it was in /etc/network/scripts.. it's not the top priority for me now but I'll keep looking for a way when I have time.